# Symfony 2 form and tab

Tags: forms, symfony, tabs

I am new to Symfony framework. The issue i have is with form. 
I managed to get data from the database and wrap it into one element and display it to the popup window. from the pop-up window only the selected items should be save on the tab which I was able to execute it using jquery.

I question is how to i save the elements from the html to the database?

Comment: Do you have any sample code of what you have tried so far?